# Sail.js: File Access

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, routes, sails.js

I'm trying to use D3 to visualize datasets in a web app built off of the Sails.js framework, but I'm having trouble with specifying to D3 where my dataset .tsv files are.

Basically, I stored a "data.tsv" in the same folder as the view that's visualizing the data. To load the data, D3 uses a function in this fashion:

```
    d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    ...
    });
```

However, when the function tries to retrieve the data, it goes to "http://www.mywebserver.com/analytics/data.tsv" and gets a 404 NOT FOUND error even though I stored data.tsv in the analytics view folder. I know this is because of the way Sails handles routing - is there any way to bypass this? What is the best way to access raw files stored in my Sails.js project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view folder is not available publicly. Only files in `.tmp/public` are available when the server is running. But don't copy files into that folder manually. It gets emptied every time the server restarts.

Files in `assets/` are copied by the grunt build tool when the server starts. You will want to put your files there. I suggest reading about sails asset management.

[Sails Assets](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/assets)

Comment: If I put my dataset in the assets folder though, how to I access it through a view file (say, views/analytics/analyze.ejs)? Also, I don't want the public to view the actual dataset files; I only want them to view the visualizations shown through d3.

Comment: You dont access it through a view file. D3 is a client side library. It doesn't run on the server.

The code `d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(data) {});` runs on the client. So the file must be available publicly, or the browser can't fetch it.

Comment: When I host the actual web app up onto a server, will I be able to hide the dataset files from public access at all? My problem is that the datasets contain sensitive information and I only want to show analytics on it.

Comment: Also, if I put data.tsv in assets/datasets/data.tsv, how do I access it? Using '../../.tmp/public/datasets/data.tsv' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Never mind, got it working! For future reference: '../../datasets/data.tsv' is the correct path.

Comment: Be careful if there is sensitive info. If the browser can get the file to show analytics, it can get the file to read the "sensitive" info too.

Comment: also...you might only need `/datasets/data.tsv`. Try it.

Comment: Hmmm, what would be your best workaround to working with sensitive information? And you're right, that works too!

Comment: You will have to avoid putting the "sensitive" parts in the TSV file. Remove names, emails, etc...

...or have authentication, and only allow certain users to view the data.